# how to limit the depth of children to return in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, tree, parent, children

I have the follow array structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 10
            [parent] => 0
            [username] => PDV
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 100
                            [parent] => 10
                            [username] => Terminal de Vendas
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 101
                            [parent] => 10
                            [username] => Clientes
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 102
                            [parent] => 10
                            [username] => Fechamento
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 103
                            [parent] => 10
                            [username] => Relatórios de Venda
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1004
                                            [parent] => 103
                                            [username] => Relatório de Venda 1
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1005
                                            [parent] => 103
                                            [username] => Relatório de Venda 2
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 11
            [parent] => 0
            [username] => Estoque
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 111
                            [parent] => 11
                            [username] => Cadastro de produtos
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 112
                            [parent] => 11
                            [username] => Entrada Produtos
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 113
                            [parent] => 11
                            [username] => Relatórios de Estoque
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1104
                                            [parent] => 113
                                            [username] => Relatório de Estoque A
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1105
                                            [parent] => 113
                                            [username] => Relatório de Estoque B
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 13
            [parent] => 0
            [username] => Financeiro
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 126
                            [parent] => 13
                            [username] => Notas de Entrada
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 127
                            [parent] => 13
                            [username] => Notas de Saída
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 128
                            [parent] => 13
                            [username] => Vendas Diárias
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 129
                            [parent] => 13
                            [username] => Balanço
                        )
                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 130
                            [parent] => 13
                            [username] => Relatórios
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1301
                                            [parent] => 130
                                            [username] => Relatório 1
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [parent] => 0
            [username] => Sistema
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 107
                            [parent] => 12
                            [username] => Ajuda...
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1008
                                            [parent] => 107
                                            [username] => Conteúdo...
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1009
                                            [parent] => 107
                                            [username] => Licença
                                        )
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1100
                                            [parent] => 107
                                            [username] => Sobre...
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 118
                            [parent] => 12
                            [username] => Usuários
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1200
                                            [parent] => 118
                                            [username] => Cadastro
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1303
                                            [parent] => 118
                                            [username] => Grupos
                                        )
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1201
                                            [parent] => 118
                                            [username] => Permissões
                                        )
                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1202
                                            [parent] => 118
                                            [username] => Minha Conta
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 13002
                                                            [parent] => 1202
                                                            [username] => Dados Pessoais
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => 130002
                                                                            [parent] => 12002
                                                                            [username] => TESTE 1
                                                                        )
                                                                    [1] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => 130003
                                                                            [parent] => 12002
                                                                            [username] => TESTE 2
                                                                        )
                                                                )
                                                        )
                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 12003
                                                            [parent] => 1202
                                                            [username] => Alterar Senha
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => 130004
                                                                            [parent] => 12003
                                                                            [username] => TESTE 3
                                                                        )
                                                                )
                                                        )
                                                    [2] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 1204
                                                            [parent] => 1202
                                                            [username] => Sair
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 125
                            [parent] => 12
                            [username] => Preferências
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 119
                            [parent] => 12
                            [username] => Configuração
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

I've been working for hours and my head is cracking. Please, can anyone give me a light on how to limit the depth of children to return?

I want get a part of this structure. For example: With base on ID 118, return no parents and 1 level of childrens from this ID.
Them call a function:

```
$result = TreePartByID($source, 118, null, 1);

$source     Is the full array structure;
118         Is the ID to use as item base;
null        Is the number of parents to return from the ID 118. In this case, null represents the some iten with ID 118;
1           Is a depth of childrens to return from ID 118. This case is only immediate childrens relative to ID 118;
```

$result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 118
            [parent] => 12
            [username] => Usuários
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1200
                            [parent] => 118
                            [username] => Cadastro
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1303
                            [parent] => 118
                            [username] => Grupos
                        )
                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1201
                            [parent] => 118
                            [username] => Permissões
                        )
                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1202
                            [parent] => 118
                            [username] => Minha Conta
                            [children] => true
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

The function:

parameters:

```
$ID        = ID of iten defined as default;
$parents   = Number of parents from the $ID. If null, retur the own $ID, else if 0(zero) return from the root and any number is the number of parents;
$childrens = Number of childrens from the $ID. if 0(zero) no return childrens;
```

```
function TreePartByID($ID, $parents=0, $childrens=1){

    ...

    return $arrayResult;
}
```

TreePartByID(118) Result: o path completo referente ao item 118

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 12
            [parent] => 0
            [username] => Sistema
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 118
                            [parent] => 12
                            [username] => Usuários
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1200
                                            [parent] => 118
                                            [username] => Cadastro
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1303
                                            [parent] => 118
                                            [username] => Grupos
                                        )
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1201
                                            [parent] => 118
                                            [username] => Permissões
                                        )
                                    [3] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1202
                                            [parent] => 118
                                            [username] => Minha Conta
                                            [children] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 13002
                                                            [parent] => 1202
                                                            [username] => Dados Pessoais
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => 130002
                                                                            [parent] => 12002
                                                                            [username] => TESTE 1
                                                                        )
                                                                    [1] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => 130003
                                                                            [parent] => 12002
                                                                            [username] => TESTE 2
                                                                        )
                                                                )
                                                        )
                                                    [1] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 12003
                                                            [parent] => 1202
                                                            [username] => Alterar Senha
                                                            [children] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [0] => Array
                                                                        (
                                                                            [id] => 130004
                                                                            [parent] => 12003
                                                                            [username] => TESTE
                                                                        )
                                                                )
                                                        )
                                                    [2] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [id] => 1204
                                                            [parent] => 1202
                                                            [username] => Sair
                                                        )
                                                )
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

TreePartByID(1202, 1, 1); // retorna 1 item como parent(118), e filhos imediatos do ID 1202 (1 nível);

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 118
            [parent] => 12
            [username] => Usuários
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1202
                            [parent] => 118
                            [username] => Minha Conta
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 13002
                                            [parent] => 1202
                                            [username] => Dados Pessoais
                                            [children] => true
                                        )
                                    [1] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 12003
                                            [parent] => 1202
                                            [username] => Alterar Senha
                                            [children] => true
                                        )
                                    [2] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 1204
                                            [parent] => 1202
                                            [username] => Sair
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

Comment: Where is the code where you create these arrays? Or the content of `TreePartByID()`??

Comment: I not have a code on this function - Is it that I want|

Comment: json_decode() has a nesting depth parameter, if that helps ...

Comment: @dormilich, the json_decode depth param only test the depth of data. If the data have more depth of informed in this param the result is null;